# strapi collection types in gatsby missing

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have created some single types and som collection types in strapi. In my gatsby project, in the the gatsby-config.js file, I have placed the names of the single types and the collection type.

```
collectionTypes: ['heronodes'],
singleTypes: ['message', 'intro', 'hero', 'footer'],
```

I can see all the single types in the graphql playground in gatsby, but none of the collection type nodes are visible in the graphql explorer.

I have checked the proper permissions for the collection type heronode and tested the api in the browser on http://localhost:1337/api/heronodes and I am getting a proper result set.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer is that the name of the collection type must be singular :)